# How to register a custom ObjectMapper with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am planning to create my own custom Object Mapper for a type using AutoMapper's IObjectMapper interface, but I don't see any place where we can register the implemented mapper with AutoMapper. Could anyone tell me how to register it.

Edit: For more information on this please follow the [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/automapper-users/browse_thread/thread/7ce461a77ee2c71d/e6fd492d7a8b2960#e6fd492d7a8b2960) at AutoMapper-Users group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go here is to replace the static registry function in the MapperRegistry class.  Here's the current version:

```
public static Func<IEnumerable<IObjectMapper>> AllMappers = () => new IObjectMapper[]
{
#if !SILVERLIGHT
    new DataReaderMapper(),
#endif
    new TypeMapMapper(TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.AllMappers()),
    new StringMapper(),
    new FlagsEnumMapper(),
    new EnumMapper(),
    new ArrayMapper(),
    new EnumerableToDictionaryMapper(),
    new DictionaryMapper(),
#if !SILVERLIGHT
    new ListSourceMapper(),
#endif
    new EnumerableMapper(),
    new AssignableMapper(),
    new TypeConverterMapper(),
    new NullableMapper()
};
```

You'd basically copy that one, and do something like:

```
MapperRegistry.AllMappers = () => new IObjectMapper[] {
   // Insert your custom mapper somewhere in this list
};
```

Just do that before you do any Mapper.CreateMap or Mapper.Initialize business.  Mappers are evaluated in order.